# Freemember update_profile with member photo?

Tags: freemember

I'm using freemember to update a member's profile, which is working great. However I now need to add member photo into the mix but I cannot figure out how to get this to work in that photos are not being uploaded. Are the any examples of an update form with member photo?

Answer (score 1):

Member profile pictures and avatars are not supported yet officially by Freemember, but there is an open pull request which adds support for this and needs some beta testers.

You can grab a copy of Freemember with upload support directly [here](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/archive/avatar.zip), and [add any feedback or comments to the GitHub pull request](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/pull/35).

I'll update this answer once this feature is released officially.